# Exposing Static Constant with Boost

Tags: c++, python, boost

I am using Boost 1.44.0 to cross-compile C++ code for Python. I'm trying to expose a static constant defined in ExposureSinusoid.h like this:

```
static const UINT _min_exp = 20;
```

And in the file extending.cpp, I am trying to expose them like this, according to documentation from the Boost team:

```
.def_readonly("_min_exp", &ExposureSinusoid::_min_exp)
```

The library compiles fine but when the program runs I get the following error:

```
ImportError: ../linux/appfs/master/usr/lib/python2.6/pa/vision/_vision.so: undefined symbol: _ZN16ExposureSinusoid8_min_expE
```

To rule out the possibility the Boost wasn't finding the constant, I tried changing its name in extending.cpp and the library failed to compile. So it seems like the constant is being found during compilation but it isn't being properly exposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to being *declared*, `static` data members must also be *defined*.

```cpp
// ExposureSinusoid.h
class ExposureSinusoid
{
    // ...
public:
    static const UINT _min_exp = 20;   // declaration
    // ...
};

// ExposureSinusoid.cpp
const UINT ExposureSinusoid::_min_exp; // definition
```

The only scenario where the definition of a `static` data member may be omitted is when the data member in question is a `const` fundamental integral type, *and* it is initialized with a constant expression, *and* it is never ODR-used (see the C++03 standard, §9.4.2/4); however, taking the address of a variable qualifies as ODR-usage, so in your case a definition must be supplied.

Comment: can't do assignment like that in the class body. The assignment needs to be with the definition.

Comment: @crashmstr : Inline initialization is allowed for (and only for) `static` data members that are `const` fundamental integral types initialized with constant expressions.

Comment: Is that from one of the newer c++ specs?

Comment: @crashmstr : No, it's in the C++03 standard, §9.4.2/4.

Comment: I'm a bit out of date then, since I don't have a 9.4 in my book (3rd Edition).

Comment: @crashmstr : I assume you're referring to "The C++ Programming Language" book by Mr. Stroustrup. However, I'm referring to ISO/IEC 14882:2003, the formal language specification -- different books. :-]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, this problem is fixed now. I've been working mainly with Python lately so it looks like I need to brush up on my C++. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 3):

Static linkage means that the symbol is *not* visible outside the TU! Change `static` to `extern` (because global constants are implicitly static):

```
extern const UINT _min_exp = 20;
```

---

*Correction:* I didn't see that `_min_exp` was a member variable, apologies. In that case the answer is, as ildjarn already said, to add the *definition* of the variable outside the class definition. To be sure, both the declaration and the initialization go *inside*, but the definition goes outside:

```
struct Foo {
  static const int a = 1; // initialization can go inside the class definition
};
const int Foo::a;         // definition (this is what the linker sees)
```

Comment: `_min_exp` is not a global variable, it is a data member of `class ExposureSinusoid`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. Yes, in that case you have to actually define the variable outside the class.