# exposing constant in Boost.Python outside of any class scope

Tags: python, boost, boost-python

I have following constant in C++ code

```
enum
{
    BOUNDARY_NONE = -1,
};
```

I would like to expose it to Python with Boost.Python so that it will be available in Python as just `BOUNDARY_NONE`. I dont want to define it under any aditional scope.

I found how to do this with Boost.Python v1

```
#include <boost/python/reference.hpp>
my_module_builder.add(make_ref(BOUNDARY_NONE), "BOUNDARY_NONE");
```

But I use newer version of Python and I dont know how to access to my_module_builder with it (I use BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE instead).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877587/exposing-static-constant-with-boost) similar question appears but they are adding constant to class scope, and I dont have any class scope to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't found anything better than:

```
scope().attr("BOUNDARY_NONE") = BOUNDARY_NONE;
```